# Get database type of ActiveRecord object attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say I have this in schema.rb:

```
create_table "products" do |t|
 t.string   "name",                                           
 t.text     "description"
end
```

I want a way to find out what the database type of a product attribute is.

Something like: `Product.column_type(:name) => "string"`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Product.columns_hash['name'].type # => :string
```

Note the using of strings instead of symbols.

**About an alternative: sql_type**

It maps logical Rails types to DB-specific data types. For *general purpose things* I wouldn't recommend using it: your production DB-engine will return the value which won't be the same as the `sql_type` for the very same column in your development DB (although they both were created with the same migration file). Example for boolean field:

```
# SQLite mapping:
:boolean => { :name => "boolean" }
# MySQL mapping:
:boolean => { :name => "tinyint", :limit => 1 }
```

Using `type` in both cases give you `:boolean`, as you specify in migrations.

Comment: Perfect! Do you know the difference between the type and sql_type attributes? I can't find it in the docs: http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Column

Comment: Great, although the giant bold text is a little frightening :). Accepted